# Recurrence Relation with absolute value?

Tags: recurrence-relations, absolute-value

If I have the following recurrence relation:

$$
\displaylines{\begin{align}F_0 &= 1 \\\ F_n &= F_{n-1} + |9-n| \end{align}}$$
Is there a closed form solution?

Comment: Let $G_n := F_{n+9}$ given by $G_0 = \alpha = F_9$ and $G_{n+1} = G_n + (n-9)$. And for $F_i$ for $i < 9$, it's just a finite set, you can calculate it easily.

Comment: $F_1$ through $F_9$ can be calculated directly. For $n > 9$ you have $F_{n} = F_9 + {{n-8}\choose{2}}$ (Hint: Calculate the sum (10-9) + (11-9) + (12-9) + ... to obtain this result)

Comment: Ok thanks, this was the direction I had planned to take but couldn't find any examples online, I was wondering if there was something more clever as I'm scaling up to a larger problem with several absolute values with lots of terms. Seems reasonable to just make a piecewise function, splitting off when the values inside the absolute value are at 0